# Salesforce Lightning Enhanced Notes in Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Is it possible to open out of the box "Salesforce Lightning Enhanced Notes" editor on click of a link / button so that we have more control over our lightning UI screen.

If we see on below screenshot, when user clicks on "Notes" from bottom utility bar, we want to launch "Salesforce Lightning Enhanced Notes" editor.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, you can it can be like this:

```
({
    openFirstUtility : function(component, event, helper) {
        var utilityAPI = component.find("utilitybar");
        utilityAPI.getAllUtilityInfo().then(function(response) {
            var myUtilityInfo = response[0];
            utilityAPI.openUtility({
                utilityId: myUtilityInfo.id
            });
       })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
})
```

more details:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_openUtility.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_getUtilityInfo.htm

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar requirement and I tried the solution suggested by Abhijith. I was able to open Note utility, but not a particular note from the list of notes. Wondering if there is a way to actually open a particular note or blank note editor instead of the whole Note utility.

Comment: i am also looking for solution to open a Note through the Enhanced Note popup window.

have you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link that will provide a solution to the standard notes without writing any custom code.
[Open particular note in enhanced note editor in lightning experience](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297809/open-particular-note-in-enhanced-note-editor-in-lightning-experience)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.